# Efficiently project 2D plane onto 1D line

Tags: algorithm, graph, line, projection, plane

I have a array of `[width, height, x, y]` vectors, like so: `[[width_1, height_1, x_1, y_1],...,[width_n, height_n, x_n, y_n]]` representing a 2D plane of blocks. This vector is potentially long (n > 10k).

An example:

[image]

must be projected like:

[image]

The problem is however that the blocks are not neatly stacked, but can be in any shape and position

[image]

The criterion for which block should be project doesn't really matter. In the example I took the first (on the x-axis) largest; which seems reasonable.

What is important is that a list (vector) is maintained of which other blocks were occluded by the projected block. The blocks bear metadata which is important, so I should be able to answer the question "to what line segment was this block projected?"

So concretely how can a 2D plane be efficiently projected onto a line, in a sense "cast a shadow", in a way that maintains a method of seeing what blocks partake in a line segment (shadow)?

**Edit**: while the problem is rather generic, the concrete problem is that I have a document that has multiple columns and floating images for which I would like to generate a "minimap" which indicates where to find certain annotations (colors)

Comment: how do you decide what block gets projected and which does not? do you want to keep history for each block? It is not entirely clear what you want...

Comment: @ChrisMaes in the example I assumed the "first largest". In the edit I explain the problem more concretely. I have a document (like html) for which I would like to generate a "minimap" which is able to show annotations. Aesthetically larger blocks are prettier than a bunch of smaller ones, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the rectangles are always aligned with the axes, as in your example, I would use a [sweep line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) approach:

1. Sort the rectangle tops/bottoms according to their y value. For every element, keep a reference to the full rectangle data.
2. Scan the list in increasing y order, maintaining a set S of rectangles representing the rectangles that contain the current y value. For every top of a rectangle r, add r to S. Similarly, for every bottom of r, remove r from S. Every time you do it, a segment is being closed and a new one is started. If you inspect S at this point, you have all the rectangles that participate in the segment, so this is the place to apply a policy for choosing the segment color.

If you need to know later what segments a rectangle belongs to, you can build a mapping between rectangles and segments lists, and update it during the scan.